# S-box and Side Channel Attacks

Tags: s-boxes, side-channel-attack

S-boxes with non-linearity greater than 112 are considered prone to side channel attacks. 
If a non-linear S- box with non- linearity greater than 112 (excluding bent functions with non-linearity of 120) is implemented through lookup tables, then the amount of power consumption should be similar to 112 S-box. In other words, side channel attacks shouldn't be able to distinguish between the two S-boxes. The question is, if an S-box with non-linearity greater than 112, implemented through look ups is safe or not?

Comment: "S-boxes with non-linearity greater than 112 are considered prone to side channel attacks"; huh?  Where are you getting this from?  Side channel attacks attack the implementation, not necessarily the sbox contents...

Comment: @poncho, S-boxes with high non-linearity are composed of complex functions. If S-box is not implemented through Look up table, then for computing S-box output, for each input, complex computations are done. These complex computations might lead to attacks eg timing attack. An S-layer taking longer time to compute shows presence of complex functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have mis-understanding and misconception of how nonlinearity of sbox influences on side channel.

The 112 is nonlinear value of good properties sbox (such as AES) , I have not seen sbox with greater value in my literature.

I will go beyond you question, to evaluate s-box against side channel attack such as differential power analysis (DPA), other parameters are taken : **Transparency order (TO)** (the lower the TO, provides higher resistance to DPA) and **signal to noise ratio (SNR)** ( the lower the SNR ,provides  higher resistance to DPA).

Prouff showed in his paper ([DPA Attacks and S-Boxes](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bea1/fc8a9e026308b1db519256f4bbdad1c0c4c3.pdf)), the highly nonlinear s-box are prone to DPA and   the construction of highly-nonlinear S-boxes with small transparency order (close to 0) is an open problem.

I recommend you download the SET tool from this [link](https://sidesproject.wordpress.com/publications/) and start to play it with different constructions of Sbox to gain more knowledge